# Visual studio 2010 c++ won't compile changes, must always clean

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

It been happening for a while now, that every time I make changes to my code and compile, the behavior of program won't reflect the changes I made. What i have to do to get a change is to clean my project and compile all the files again. Visual studio shouldn't be doing this and its starting get in the way of actually debugging my code to begin with as the program is large and it takes a while to compile.

How can I fix this so I don't have to go through this ritual of cleaning then compiling just to see changes.

Comment: Have you set the correct time in your computer?

Comment: yes the time is set on my computer

Comment: Are you using and making changes to precompiled headers?

Comment: changes to headers I've made, yes, precompiled, not entirely sure what you mean, I am a novice after all. Most of the changes I'm making now is inside my own class which is included onto the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your sources on some network/mounted drive? That may confuse the build.
My experience is that it can miss a dependency with some 1% chance on random files, but no more than that.

If they are not, in options/build&run you can set diag level of build to higher and see what steps are considered for build. Also you can look the discovered depencencies in the intermediate files folder, the .tlog files. You may also try to look at debug output [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) though most of the latter belongs to discovering excess compilations...